# How to enable Inbox by Gmail for a Google for Work account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, inbox-by-gmail

I want to enable *Inbox by Gmail* for my Google for Work account. This page tells me that it's available and how to find the checkbox to enable it. https://support.google.com/a/answer/6082718

I followed the steps provided on that page, but I don't see the checkbox *Inbox by Gmail* within Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Gmail > Advanced settings > End User Settings

[image]

From my Gmail account, I already sent an invite to my Google for Work email address.

Do I need to wait a bit longer or is the checkbox to be found somewhere else?

Comment: Only the administrator can enable Inbox for Apps for Work.

Comment: I am an admin of the Google for Work domain

Comment: That seems to be a glitch, you need to wait a bit longer

Comment: AFAIK, Inbox by Gmail for Google Apps for Work is still part of the early adopter program -> http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/05/expanding-inbox-by-gmail-early-adopter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to wait. In my case, the checkbox appeared about a week after I sent an invite from my Gmail account to my Google Apps for Work admin account.

[image: Inbox by Gmail checkbox in Google Apps for Work admin]

Answer (score 2):

It has been moved to regular User Settings, not advanced. See docs [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6082718?hl=en)

[image]